# Using OOB Error Rate to improve Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, bagging

I've been reading about the use of OOB Error Rate and its applications and use in Random Forest, for which some curiosity is how I could further use this value in the optimization of my own modelling process.

With this I was curious if it was possible to trace back the splits that are erroneous, thus misclassified. This because I wish to additionally features that can help improve the classification of a specific class.

I already have the OOB values per each class, showing whether some samples that are not used in a specific get classified correctly.

Thus I want to know what these samples are actually being classified as, for which I could add specific genes to enhance that classification.

Thank you in advanced and I hope that this was clear enough.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [confusion matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95209/how-can-i-interpret-a-confusion-matrix)?

Comment: Error rates and the confusion matrix have [fundamental problems](https://fharrell.com/post/mlconfusion) and my experience with random forest has been that its true accuracy (closeness of the calibration curve to the line of identify) is some of the worst I've ever seen due to extreme overfitting.